# Can I use an ephemeral port number for a permanent service?

Tags: port-forwarding

For example configure my router at home to forward all connections to a certain port `> 32768` to a local SSH server. Would this maybe block outgoing connections because a client randomly selected the same port number as ephemeral port?

Comment: There are no issues doing this, people do it all the time. A TCP connection is determined by 4 values, the source and destination addresses and the source and destination ports. Usually when you make a connection you ask the system to choose an unused source port, so this is enough to mean the connection differs from all others.

Comment: No. It's not the userland program which randomly selects a port number, but the kernel, when the program calls `connect()`, `listen()` or `sendto()` on an unbound socket, or `bind()` with a port = 0. If the program tries to `bind()` to a socket already in use, it will get an `EADDRINUSE` error. You should eat up _all the ports_ in the ephemeral range, in order to cause `connect()` on a new socket to result in an `EADDRNOTAVAIL` error.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I may was not clear enough wotj my question, with "client" I referred to any client inside a network and an external device (the router) forwards its own external port to a certain device. My question then is if a client will have problems to connect to an external server because it does not know that the port it selected is blocked. Sorry, I may asked the question in the wrong sub forum as it is not so UNIX specific.